# Open an app from the foreground service when the app is closed

Tags: java, android

So I am using this code to open another app using mine (Android Studio, Java):

```
Intent i = getFeatureManager().getMainMenu().getMainActivity().getPackageManager().
                getLaunchIntentForPackage(getSettingByName("Launch Package").getSValue());

        if (i == null) {
            return;
        }
        getFeatureManager().getMainMenu().getMainActivity().startActivity(i);
```

and I have foreground service and when my app is running in the background and my app is closed nothing happens how can I make that work even when my app is closed

The only thing I've found related to this is something saying its not possible when I know it is from another apps, I have an app that can open itself and the app always runs in the foreground

Comment: "how can I make that work even when my app is closed" -- background activity starts [are not possible on Android 10 and higher](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts) except in limited scenarios.

Comment: I have an app that can open itself from the foreground

Comment: I have no idea what "open itself from the foreground" means, sorry.

Comment: the app is always running in the background and can open itself

Comment: Then hopefully that app fits within the limited scenarios mentioned in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts).

Comment: so how can I make that work in my app

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this we need to add the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission to the AndroidManifest.xml

As shown below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

and accept the popup above other apps in the android app settings